# How check if a transaction is cancelled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm developing a web app that receive payments, for handle payments I'm using Stripe, when I receive a payment I block it until a certain action occur, then I capture it.
And I have for every payment a row in my db table that have some info about it.

Stripe rules allow to block a payment for max 7 days, and its ok for me, but How can I refresh my db after 7 days to set the payment to cancelled?
Because for stripe is cancelled but for my db if I dont updated it the payment is still in pending, do you think I need to add a "creation_date" attribute? and then every day check it??

This is my payments table:

payments:

- id
- user_id
- stripe_payment_id
- status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) for this. If the PaymentIntent is uncaptured for 7 days it'll be automatically cancelled and Stripe will send you a `payment_intent.cancelled` event: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later#overview

Comment: Oh thanks! At the moment for check if payments is succeed I just check the response status after confirm the payment, do you think I should use webhooks for that as well?

Comment: You sure can: https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.succeeded